# flex sdk into xcode

Tags: xcode, air

Is it possible to use xcode to develop adobe air application??

how to install flex 4 sdk into xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible! ...as far as I know!
Install flash builder

Comment: Haha, I don't want to pay any money :P

Answer (score 0):

I read from somewhere that eclipse can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it work in XCODE, But it works in Eclipse Please Check [this](http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/)